# iPhone CSS :focus not working

Tags: css, iphone, focus

I have simplified a test for the `:focus` pseudo class. Here is the HTML:

```
<span id="test" tabindex="1">Hello</span>
```

and the CSS:

```
span#test:focus {
    color: red;
}
```

When I click on the span on the desktop, it works as expected (changes the colour to red). However, when I touch it on my iPhone, it doesn’t.

I can get it to work if the `:focus` is changed to `:hover`, but I don’t want that for the desktop version, since I want it to wait until until the user clicks.

I may have to resort to JavaScript, but is there a CSS solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: `:focus` is typically used on `<a>`, `<button>`, `<input>` and `<textarea>`, practically all **interaction** elements that you can reach by *tabbing* through the page. It'd be new to me that it is available on arbitrary elements (like `<p>`, `<span>` or `<div>`)  as well.

Comment: @connexo On the desktop, it can be used on any element, as long as you make it focussable, with, say, a `tabindex` attribute. These elements can also be tabbed on, though it’s not always a pretty sight.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that iphone have 320px width or higher depending of models, peharps media query can be an alternative solution:

```
span#test:focus {
   color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
   span#test:hover {
      color: red;
   }
}
```

Comment: I’m reluctant to use a media query in this way, since screen size doesn’t imply a feature set. In any case, this would not work for other iPhone screen sizes, or possibly for other mobile platforms.